# Procedure which creates table along with dates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to create a dyamic procedure which accepts tablename, startdate and enddate
which goes like this `

```
alter procedure task_date @tablename nvarchar(max), @start as datetime,@end as datetime
as begin

declare @t1 as nvarchar(max)
declare @t2 as nvarchar(max)

set @t1='create table '+@tablename+'_'+@start+'(int id)'
set @t1='create table '+@tablename+'_'+@end+'(int id)'

exec(@t1)
exec(@t2)
end
```

`

If I pass parameters to my stored procedure like this

```
`exec task_date name,'21/2/2017','24/2/2016`'
```

Then it should create two tables  as `abc_21Feb2017` , `abc_22Feb2017`, `abc_23Feb2017`, `abc_24Feb2017`, Means difference between the dates also should be created as tables along with startdate and enddate with underscore seperation

**Note:** My code is wrong here, i want the proper code along with correct logic, help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try following solution:

```
DECLARE @StartDate  DATE = '2017-02-22';
DECLARE @EndDate    DATE = '2017-02-24';

DECLARE @SqlStatement NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

WITH Num10(Number)
AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10
),
Num100(Number)
AS (
    SELECT (a.Number - 1)*10 + b.Number FROM Num10 a CROSS JOIN Num10 b
)
SELECT  @SqlStatement = @SqlStatement 
            + N'CREATE TABLE ' + N'dbo.CocoJamboTable' + N'_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), DATEADD(DAY, n.Number - 1, '2017-02-22'), 106), ' ', '') + N'(INT ID)'
            + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
FROM    Num100 n
WHERE   n.Number <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1;
PRINT @SqlStatement
--EXEC sp_executesql @SqlStatement
```

This will generate and execute(`--UNCOMMENT LAST LINE`) following script:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CocoJamboStupidNameTable_22Feb2017(ID INT)
CREATE TABLE dbo.CocoJamboStupidNameTable_23Feb2017(ID INT)
CREATE TABLE dbo.CocoJamboStupidNameTable_24Feb2017(ID INT)
```

**Edit 1:**

[1] N10 and N100 CTEs returns all numbers between 1 and 10 or 1 and 100.
These CTEs could be replaced with a table with numbers. An example of such table can be found [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained--part-1/).

[2] Main SELECT statement returns numbers (starting with 1) from N100 CTE or from number table.

[3] `DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1` compute number of days between @StartDate and @EndDate including (+1) last one (@EndDate). For example, number of days between 2017-02-22 and 2017-02-24 isn't 2 (24 - 22) but 2 + 1 = 3 (if we take into account 22 but also 24).

[4] `WHERE   n.Number <= DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1;` filter all numbers between 1 and number of days (= difference between start date and end date).

[5] `SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n.Number - 1, '2017-02-22')` compute all dates between start date and also end date: 2017-02-22, 23, 24.

[6] `SELECT N'CREATE TABLE .... DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, ...` will generate the SQL `CREATE TABLE` scripts for every date between start date and end date.

Comment: int id should be id int?

Comment: ya correct it should be id int, correct me in few places

Comment: @P.Salmon: Updated. Thanks.

Comment: any alternate answer, because i don't want to come across complexities of unions and all

Comment: @navs: Could you please rephrase/explain following sentence "i don't want to come across complexities of ... **and all** –" ?

Comment: you have taken union and common table expression for your codes right?

Comment: Those two CTEs are used only to generate all numbers between 1 and 100.

Comment: You could replace `FROM    Num100 n` with `FROM    dbo.Num n` where dbo.Num table has a single column: Number INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY. This table should have 100 or more rows dependind how big is period between start date and end date.

Comment: See also: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4176/the-sql-server-numbers-table-explained--part-1/

Comment: hi, can you explain you code please, i am getting desired output, but din;t understood the logic, can you try explaining with comments please

Comment: @navs: See **Edit 1**

Comment: @navs: If you have more questions just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

A simple while loop with a test on date might suffice

```
use sandbox
go
drop procedure p
go
CREATE procedure [dbo].[p] 
@start   date ,
@end     date
as
declare @t  nvarchar(max) 

while   @start <= @end 
begin
 set @t=    concat('create table abc_',replace(cast(@start as varchar(10)),'-','_'),char(40), 'id int' ,char(41))

 print @t
 EXEC sp_executesql @t
 set @start = dateadd(d,1,@start)

end

GO

exec dbo.p '2017-06-21','2017-06-25'

select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_name like 'abc%'
```

Result

```
table_name
--------------
abc_2017_06_21
abc_2017_06_22
abc_2017_06_23
abc_2017_06_24
abc_2017_06_25
```

Note the use of ascii characters for left and right parenthesis and the replace to remove illegal - in table name.